# Templavoila - Extra space in content when "Typoscript Only" or "Object Path"

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, templavoila

This has been bothering me a little for a while and I couldn't find any other mention of that problem anywhere. It is not really important, but maybe there's a simple solution that I'm missing.

When creating a FCE, some Elements are **Typoscript only** or **Typoscript Object Path**.
When I set those, I get blank extra space in the content (In picture, see between *Content* and *Description*). This is an empty `<div class="form-section">`, just like the other fields but empty.

Is there a way to prevent **Templavoilà Plus** from displaying a field if no content is required from the redactor, meaning if they are an Typoscript Object Path for exemple?

[image: Empty <code><div></code> between <code>Content</code> and <code>Description</code>]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please create an issue report about this on https://github.com/pluspol-interactive/templavoilaplus/issues and post an example DataStructure for this.

Thanks

Comment: By your answer I assume that this is not something I did or did not do, but something that as to do with how TV was made? It's like nobody ever noticed though. I will create an issue report, hopefully we can edit your answer someday. In the meantime, do you have some kind of workaround for this?

Comment: This can mean, that I overlooked something. I know we needed changes in that area for working with TYPO3 7/8 LTS ... maybe I missed something. Will take a look into it.
While checking this issue I may write a workaround IMHO ther was a way to set fields hidden.